# Arraylist of Objects - How do I remove an entry?

Tags: java, swing, object, arraylist

I am doing homework and it states that I have to be able to remove a entry from an arraylist of objects.

I try to check if it contains the user id I want to remove but objects cannot contain strings

```
 public class EmployeeProgramView extends FrameView {
 ArrayList <information> database = new ArrayList <information>();


private void exitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    System.exit(0);
}                                          

private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    information a;
    String ID, firstName, lastName, startDate, annualSalary, linedUp;
    ID = idInput.getText();
    firstName = firstNameInput.getText();
    lastName = lastNameInput.getText();
    startDate = startInput.getText();
    annualSalary = salaryInput.getText();
    linedUp = (firstName+" "+lastName+" "+annualSalary+" "+startDate);

    a = new information (ID, firstName, lastName, startDate,annualSalary);
    database.add(a);

    System.out.println(linedUp);
}                                         

private void listButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            String temp="";

    for (int x=0; x<=database.size()-1; x++) {
        temp = temp + database.get(x).ID + " "
                + database.get(x).first + " "
                + database.get(x).last + " "
                + database.get(x).start + " "
                + database.get(x).salary + "\n";
    }
    finalOutput.setText(temp);

}

private void removeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String removeID;
    removeID = idInput.getText();


    if (database.contains(removeID)){
    database.remove(removeID);

    } else {
    finalOutput.setText("No such ID in database");
    }
}

class information{
String ID, first, last, start, salary;

    information(String _ID ,String _first, String _last, String _start, String _salary){
        ID = _ID;
        first = _first;
        last = _last;
        start = _start;
        salary = _salary;
    }
}
```

}

So my question is? How do I remove a object?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you aware of the `List<T>#remove` method? Why can't you use this?

Comment: Explore the API read the JavaDoc of [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 1):

The [remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) method will remove an object from array as long as [.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) returns true when comparing that object and the object we are asking to remove. This is true for identical strings; other objects by defaults are only equal to themselves (still, you can add an object to array and retain another variable referring to it).

You can also always remove just [by array index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29).

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to use the method: List < T > #remove, to remove the object in question

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through the Array and find the ID you are looking for.  Just add this into your main class:

```
public void removeInformation(ArrayList<Information> database, String removeID) {
    for(int i = 0; i < database.size(); i++) {
        if(database.get(i).getID().equals(removeID)) {
            database.remove(database.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

This is unrelated to your question, but by convention classes are named with a capital letter, so your "information" class should be titled "Information".

Also, I just wanted to say that, in case you didn't know, before you type your class you can type import statements.  For example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
```

This way you don't have to type "java.awt.event.ActionListener actionListener" every time you want to use that class.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Thanks everyone for their input. really got my brain thinking different ways haha.

```
    private void removeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String temp, removeID;
    removeID = idInput.getText();

    for (int x = 0; x<=database.size()-1; x++){
           temp = database.get(x).ID;
           if(removeID.equals(temp)){
           database.remove(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Might want to be careful -- if you have two objects in a row that you want to remove, this method will skip the second one.

Comment: Go backwards through list to fix that problem. for (int x = database.size()-1; x>=0; x--){

Answer (score -1):

see basically,

you need to remove an object information from arraylist if the list contains information whose id is same as removeid.

so before removing , you need to do a check for the information id in the list

so go for iterating list and find information in each iteration and check its id equlas to removeid

if equals then do list.remove(information)

```
for (Information information: database) {
    // check for ID is same as remove id
   // if equals remove that entire object from list

    if (information.ID.equals(removeID)) {
        // remove object with ID same as removeid
        database.remove(information);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the same answer as user432's answer, and won't work if `Information#equals()` isn't implemented by testing `ID`s for equality. If `equals()` is implemented by comparing `ID`s, this duplicates work already done by `remove()`.

Comment: see first of all..its my own view of answering..not copy paste...second String class has already overriden equals method and also information.id and removeid both are strings so no need of any extra things here..whats your doubt ?

Comment: I didn't say it's a copy/paste, I just said it's the same answer as the (now deleted) answer. And take a look at `ArrayList#remove(Object o)`. When you try to remove an object the `equals()` method of the passed object, so your answer depends on more than just `String#equals()`. In addition, `ArrayList#remove(Object o)` already does a traversal of the `ArrayList`, so you're doing extra work here that may or may not even do what you want

Comment: i agree that passed object equality will be considered during remove of any collection not only list..but i wrote logic only for the way to showcase how to remove it..and Information class should have a proper implementation of hashcode and equals method to behave it properly with collection..

Comment: If `Information` needs to have a particular implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()`, say so in your answer. And if they have the right implementation, all you would have to do is create a new `Information` object with the desired characteristics and remove that, no need to do extra iterating work. Just consider what would happen if `Information#equals()` compared more than just the `ID` field -- this method would no longer work. The better way would be to remove by index, or use the iterator's `remove()` method.

Comment: first understand the question...he/she needs to remove the information iff the id(which is a string) is same as the removeId(which is again a string) and you have to find it by iterating the list..of course whatever the approaches you said will still work...but my solution also works fine..i am removing the object if objetc's id is same as removeId...can you tell me where exactly false can happen ?

Comment: This won't work if `Information#equals()` uses more than just `ID` to remove objects, as `ArrayList#remove()` will simply skip over the object that you wanted to remove because `equals()` will return false. That's when this won't work. I understand the question quite well. You don't understand how `ArrayList#remove()` works.

Comment: obviously , thats why id comes into picture here...equality method should be overriden in such way where if 2 information objects have same ids then all other attributes of information object must be same thats how even DB works...then only you can distingush 2 objects using equality..otherwise your index and iterator strategy also fails..

Comment: *Then why bother iterating over the `ArrayList` if `remove()` already does that?* In addition, you seem to be saying that the **only** field that matters for equality in `Information` is `ID`. That sounds **very** wrong, especially after looking at OP's code and seeing that **ID is an independent input from other significant fields**.

Comment: if you dont want to iterate, how can you find that removeId is present in the information objects of list ? and see OP's information class..it represents person's information..does not it make sense that id is the unique thing for employee or person whatever...so it should be unique..and if 2 ids are same then he must be the same person or same person's information ...

Comment: Use a `new Information()` object, perhaps? Or even better (as OP doesn't override `equals()`), iterate by index.

Comment: read fully my above comment..its updated one...and can you provide code and prove how iterate by index will solve the problem of equality if equality is not just on ID please ?

Comment: You can iterate. Iterating twice is not good though, and that's what you're doing. And I can imagine two employees having duplicate IDs -- say if one retires and some time down the road a new one *happens* to be assigned the same ID number. Sure, it'd be *nice* to have unique IDs, but I wouldn't assume such a thing, especially since OP's code gives no indication that that is the case. And for working code see OP's answer. The best thing about iterating by index is that if you later want to compare against something *else*, you don't have a big problem on your hands.

Comment: i am iterating only one not twice..where is second time iteration ? and though he has not posted we have to think of this kind of problem as unique id only..if its going to be a model for hibernate then obviously , it will become unique primary key...but anyway points you brought up were good...

Comment: Inside `remove()`. As I said before. And I think it would be ideal to *not* think of this problem as unique ID only, because if you assume unique ID you lose flexibility. What happens if OP wants to remove by name in addition to ID? Then you have to use a different solution anyways.

Comment: for (Information information: database)  is the only loop i am using and inside this if matches i am removing from list...ideal situation would go for unique id itself as i know..

Comment: Look at the source of `remove(Object o)`. There's another loop inside there. Sure, ideal situations are nice, but there's no way of telling whether this is one of them. Also, the word "homework" in the question probably precludes anything like Hibernate...

Comment: yes correct..for homework you are right..but i have written answer considering real time scenario..

Comment: Multiple iterations would almost certainly be unacceptable for a "real time scenario". A better-performing solution in that case would be iteration by indices or by using the iterator's remove() method.

Comment: i said yes correct at the start of my above comment only..why are you repeating the same again..and i think my answer is not bad enough to be down voted..anyway thats okie..